# Exit code 0x84C40013 in silient installation of SQL 2008 service pack 3 installation

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2008, sql, sql-server-2008-r2, windows-command-prompt

Following Command is utilized for installing SQL SP3 pack in Windows server 2008 R2.

```
start /WAIT C:\Temp\SQLSP3.exe /quiet /IAcceptSQLServerLicenseTerms /Action=Patch /AllInstances
```

This complete installation is happening in Administrative Privilages.

This installation failure is not happening in all server but only in fewer servers.

But i am getting the following error code in installation.
[image]

[image]

In control panel , it seems that SQL SP3 pack was installed

[image]

and SQL server still refers SQL 2008 Service Pack 1.

[image]

Please help me.

Answer (score -1):

Requires reboot to finish the installation